# for loop through csv files with multiple time steps

Tags: python, numpy, loops, csv

I am fairly new to Python so please excuse me if this is a simple problem.

Using a for loop I am trying to create a new array with mean values of concentration at varying time steps.

My simulation results have time steps as below:

```
time = np.arange(0, 51e-3, 1e-3, dtype=np.ndarray)
```

My csv file has columns like so:

'phase | phase_01 | pore.concentration@0' # concentration at time = 0

'phase | phase_01 | pore.concentration@1e-3' # concentration at time = 0.001

the list goes on...

I have tried the following:

```
for i in time:
    average_concentration_array = np.array([np.mean(advection_diffusion['phase | phase_01 | pore.concentration@%s' % i])])
```

However, when I try this I get: `KeyError: 'phase | phase_01 | pore.concentration@0.001'`

I think there is an issue with how the time step in the column is being read.

UPDATE:
I have found the issue is with the format of np.arange in my *time*. It must be as a series of strings, like so:

```
time_string = ['0','1e-3','2e-3','3e-3',.....'5e-2']
```

So when I use:

```
average_concentration = []
for i in time_string:
         average_concentration.append(np.mean(advection_diffusion['phase | phase_01 | pore.concentration@%s' % i])])
```

I achieve what I am looking to do. However, it is not practical to hard code the *time_string* as I am working with bigger simulations. The key question now: can I create a similar np.arange to my original *time* composed of strings?

[screenshot of csv file with relevant columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duZcT.png)

Comment: just saw this question and it looks interesting. Could you post some actual data from your csv file that you have imported into your array (advection_diffusion is an array, right?). Also some sample expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Ethan, advection_diffusion is only my csv file read by pandas - advection_diffusion = pd.read_csv ('./transient_advection_diffusion_data/T_AD.csv',header='infer').

Comment: A pandas data frame works fine. Can you post the top 5 rows of the data frame with column labels so I can see exactly what you are working with?

Comment: Please see updated question section

Comment: I would need some actual data pasted into your question to work with, not an image.